# Is there a way to disable WiFi auto-connect on iPhone?

Tags: iphone, wifi

Is there a way to disable automatically connecting to a known WiFi network on an iPhone?

Say that your work/school has a monitored WiFi network. You only want to connect to it when you plan on downloading a large file, so you don't want to connect to it automatically. But you also don't want to re-enter your credentials every time you want to connect.

Is there a way to tell your iPhone to forget an network until you want to re-connect?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It probably wasn't available in 2016, but it can be done in the WiFi settings now (at least since 2018):

1. Go to *Settings > WiFi*
2. Click on the ⓘ icon of your WiFi connection you want to manage
3. Disable *Auto-join*

Answer (score 2):

At this time, there is no way to do this.  Your only options are to have it always on or always off.

I suggest letting Apple know you want this feature by providing them [feedback here](http://www.apple.com/feedback/iphone.html).

Answer (score -2):

Currently, you would have to tell the iphone to forget the network and then enter your credentials again later. There is not a way to have it remember the credentials if you don't want it to automatically join.

Comment: Which is exactly what I said about an hour before your answer....

Comment: That's not what you said. You said "always on" or "always off".. are you downvoting my post because you can't stand that I added clarity to your post?

Comment: To "add clarity" to an answer you should either [add a comment to that answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment) or [edit the answer directly](https://apple.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/edit).  Adding a new answer to "add clarity" will often get you downvotes from the community.